# <article> and <section> for forum's topics?

Tags: html, forum, article

I don't know if it could be a good idea use for show a forum's topic this code:

```
<article>
    <section>First post</section>
    <section>Second post</section>
    <section>etc</section>
</article>
```

It is correct or instead I should use `<div>`?

Comment: Shouldn't individual posts be articles?

Comment: @RobertHarvey no, I'm talking about forum layout, not blog or site.

Comment: You can always refer to what W3C intended them for. Article: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article Section: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do (updated)

```
<section>
    <article>First post</article>
    <article>First post</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>Second post</article>
    <article>Second post</article>
</section>
<section>
    <article>etc</article>
    <article>etc</article>
</section>
```

Comment: But why do you?

Comment: semantics? Section is more general than Article which is a specific type of section.  Think of newspapers and how they are organized.